# Given a chord length and distance from center find length of a different chord

Tags: geometry, circles

A chord that is of length 18 cm is 12 cm away from the center of a circle. How far is a chord of length 10 cm from the center?

I know that chord of equal distance away are equidistant from the center but these are not of same length so I got a little stuck. Thank you :)

Comment: Can you find the radius from the first piece of data ? ... and use it to solve the question ?

Comment: did you consider @Shailesh comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length $l$ of a chord a distance $d$ away from the center of a circle of radius $r$ is $$l = 2{\sqrt{r^2-d^2}}$$ This can be demonstrated by the Pythagorean theorem: [Length of a Chord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBpvL.png)

In your problem, you are given $l=18$ and $d=12$, so you can use this equation to find that $r=15$. You could also forgo the equation and find the radius of the circle by recognizing the Pythagorean triple (9, 12, 15) created by $r$, $d$, and half of $l$.

Now that you know the value of r, you can find the length of the chord when $d=10$ by using the equation again. You will find that $l=10{\sqrt 5}$.